# Trying to sort an entire table by 1 variable in python

Tags: python, list, sorting

hoping someone can help me out with a problem I am working on at the moment.

I have multiple arrays being printed out into a vertical table using this code:

```
        for i, j, k, h, l, m in zip(wAarray, wBarray, rParray, vpArray,sharpeArray, utilityArray):
            print('{0:<1,.4f}{1:>20,.4f}{2:>30,.4f}{3:>40,.4f}{4:>45,.4f}{5:>50,.4f}'.format(i, j, k,h, l,m))
```

If I need to sort the whole table using the values in rParray in descending order, while keeping the table printing in the current way, how would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the question. Please show an example of *exactly* what the input looks like, and *exactly* what the output should be for that input.

Comment: What you would do is `zip` them all into a single list, and then sort that list.  Having them separate doesn't make sense if they are related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted) function. It has the keyword argument `key` which you can provide a *lambda* function taking the iteration as the only parameter. Because the value from `rParray` is the third value in the tuple, you return x[2] as the key.

```py
for i, j, k, h, l, m in sorted(zip(..., rParray, ...), key=lambda x: x[2]):
    print(...)
```